# Getting foreign key constraint incorrectly formed issue on laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

I want to build Chatter Package for my laravel 5.8 project, but getting error in this migration, file, it is trying to create table with name of database, don't know why please try to help

2016_07_29_171128_create_foreign_keys.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateForeignKeys extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('chatter_discussion', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('chatter_category_id')->references('id')->on('chatter_categories')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
        Schema::table('chatter_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('chatter_discussion_id')->references('id')->on('chatter_discussion')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('chatter_discussion', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->dropForeign('chatter_discussion_chatter_category_id_foreign');
            $table->dropForeign('chatter_discussion_user_id_foreign');
        });
        Schema::table('chatter_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('chatter_post_chatter_discussion_id_foreign');
            $table->dropForeign('chatter_post_user_id_foreign');
        });
    }
}
```

This is the ERROR that i am getting [image]

Answer (score 0):

The Foreign key needs to be formatted exactly as the key it references.

id is usually int and unsigned.

so i suggest you create the user_id column as:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because the `foreign_key` has different data type with the target table.

By default, Laravel uses `increments()` as default `id` of a table. It creates a column named `id` with `unsigned integer` as data type.

You need to define a column with `unsigned integer` to be able to create the constraint.

According to [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#foreign-keys), you need to do something like this

```
...

// Create a column with unsigned integer as type
$table->unsignedInteger('chatter_category_id');

// Then you can assign it properly
$table->foreign('chatter_category_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('chatter_categories')
      ->onDelete('cascade')
      ->onUpdate('cascade');

....
```

Comment: should I add this only for chatter_category_id, or to all columns?

Comment: Could you post your migration file for the table creation aswell?

Answer (score 0):

if use the laravel 5.8 the default field for id is  **bigIncrements**.

like this :

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

and you must use **unsignedBigInteger** type for foreign key field.

like this :

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('chatter_category_id');
```

good luck.

Comment: it is saying that column is duplicated

Comment: @NurdauletShamilov please insert the chatter_category_id table migrate to your ask.  i edited this cod for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Laravel versions and it will work for sure, there is an issue with the laravel 5.8

try like this

```
 Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
      $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
     });
```

Comment: don't want, please give proper solution